# Sorting down processes by memory usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I am able to see the list of all the processes and the memory via

```
ps aux
```

and going through the VSZ and RSS column data.

Is there a way to sort down the output of this command by the descending order on RSS value ?.

PS : This is a newbie question as I am very much new to Unix/Linux.
ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

RSS is the 6th column, so you can do it as follows:

```
ps aux | sort -k6,6 -rn
```

- sort based on column 6 *only* (the comma on `6,6` makes it, [thanks twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031490/sorting-down-processes-by-memory-usage/19031538?noredirect=1#comment28124717_19031538)), numerically and reverse (the biggest number first).

Comment: I would change that to `... | sort -k6,6 -rn` to sort on *only* column 6 instead of on "column 6 to the end of the line"...

Comment: Good one, @twalberg, I guess the result would be exactly the same (don't think there will be equal RSS) but this way it must be lighter to calculatex. Updated!

Comment: It might very well be the same in this particular case, but I've been bitten by that kind of sort specification enough times that I've just gotten in the habit of being explicit about what I mean...