# how to sort lines where sorting starts when a delimeter comes (linux)

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, delimiter

I want to sort a file which has a particular delimiter in every line. I want to sort the lines such that sorting starts from that delimeter and sorts only according to numbers.

file is like this:

```
adf234sdf:nzzs13245ekeke  
zdkfjs:ndsd34352jejs  
mkd45fei:znnd11122iens
```

output should be:

```
mkd45fei:znnd11122iens  
adf234sdf:nzzs13245ekeke  
zdkfjs:ndsd34352jejs
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-t` option to set the delimiter:

```
$ sort -t: -nk2,2 file
mkdfei:11122iens
adf234sdf:13245ekeke
zdkfjs:34352jejs
```

Comment: what does -nk2,2 means here. can you please explain

Comment: -n means numberic, while `k2,2` means the second column and just that one. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19031538/1983854 for example

Comment: what if there are alphabets before the numbers and i want to sort only from numbers. eg. mkdfei:zzhe11122iens

Comment: @user000001 i have added a constraint to the question.. can you please look into it now.

Comment: @user1660982 Fedorqui's answer should do what you want

Answer (score 2):

This can be an approach, based on [this idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41656/40596):

```
$ sed -r 's/([^:]*):([a-z]*)([0-9]*)(.*)/\1:\2-\3\4/g' a | sort -t- -k2,2 | tr -d '-'
mkdfei:aa11122iens
adf234sdf:tt13245ekeke  
zdkfjs:aa34352jejs
```

By pieces:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^:]*):([a-z]*)([0-9]*)(.*)/\1:\2-\3\4/g' a 
adf234sdf:tt-13245ekeke  
zdkfjs:aa-34352jejs  
mkdfei:aa-11122iens
$ sed -r 's/([^:]*):([a-z]*)([0-9]*)(.*)/\1:\2-\3\4/g' a | sort -t- -k2,2
mkdfei:aa-11122iens
adf234sdf:tt-13245ekeke  
zdkfjs:aa-34352jejs  
$ sed -r 's/([^:]*):([a-z]*)([0-9]*)(.*)/\1:\2-\3\4/g' a | sort -t- -k2,2 | tr -d '-'
mkdfei:aa11122iens
adf234sdf:tt13245ekeke  
zdkfjs:aa34352jejs
```

So what we do is to add a `-` character before the first number. Then we sort based on that character and finally delete `-` back (`tr -d '-'`).

Comment: actually i want to sort acc to numbers which are present after the delimeter only

Comment: so -234sdf should not be in the sorting criteria instead for 2nd line, criteria would be -13245

Comment: Oh that's true. Improving my `sed` expression.

Comment: Updated, @user1660982, now it really does.

Answer (score 1):

In `gawk` there is an `asort` function, and you could use:

```
gawk -f sort.awk data.txt
```

where `data.txt` is your input file, and `sort.awk` is

```
{ 
    line[NR]=$0;
    match($0,/:[^0-9]*([0-9]*)/,a)
    nn[NR]=a[1]" "NR
}

END {
   N=asort (nn);
   for (i=1; i<=N; i++) {
      split(nn[i],c," ")
      ind=c[2]
      print line[ind];
   }
}
```